# Parallel processing in R with mclapply: function does not work

Tags: r, windows, parallel-processing, lapply

I have quite a big set of keywords that i need to compare to an even bigger corpus of documents and count the number of occurrences.

Since the calculation takes hours, I decided to try parallel processing. On this forum, I found the mclapply function of the parallel package, which seems to be helpful.

Being very new to R, I could not get the code working (see below for a short version). More specifically, I got the error:

> "Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
>   object 'FUN' of mode 'function' was not found"

```
rm(list=ls())

df <- c("honda civic 1988 with new lights","toyota auris 4x4 140000 km","nissan skyline 2.0 159000 km")
keywords <- c("honda","civic","toyota","auris","nissan","skyline","1988","1400","159")

countstrings <- function(x){str_count(x, paste(sprintf("\\b%s\\b", keywords), collapse = '|'))}

# Normal way with one processor
number_of_keywords <- countstrings(df)
# Result: [1] 3 2 2

# Attempt at parallel processing
library(stringr)
library(parallel)
no_cores <- detectCores() - 1
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)
number_of_keywords <- mclapply(cl, countstrings(df))
stopCluster(cl)
#Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
#object 'FUN' of mode 'function' was not found
```

Any help is apprechiated!

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: Yes, I am on windows.

Comment: Tips: whenever trying to use `mclapply()`, `parLapply()` etc, start out with good-old `lapply()`. When that works, the hurdle to using `mclapply()` and friends is much smaller. (In this case, you would get the same problem with `lapply()` and knowing that might have helped you troubleshoot it yourself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function should be faster. Here's an alternate way of using parallel processing using `parSapply` (this returns a vector instead of list):

```
# function to count
count_strings <- function(x, words)
{
    sum(unlist(strsplit(x, ' ')) %in% words)
}

library(stringr)
library(parallel)
mcluster <- makecluster(detectCores()) # using all cores

number_of_keywords <- parSapply(mcluster, df, count_strings, keywords, USE.NAMES=F)

[1] 3 2 2
```